Customise layout of a bpmn diagram
I am trying to develop a bpmn-compliant process map using the bpmnR package. I have set up a basic process but am facing an issue in the render.
Sample of generated BPMN diagram:

Is there a way to show the diagram in a linear fashion from left to right?
The code I am using is:
library(dplyr)
library(bpmnR)

# Create data for BPMN elements
nodes <- tibble(id = "task", name = "Task name",
               objectType = "task", gatewayDirection = NA)
events <- tibble(id = c("start", "end"), 
                 name = c("Start event", "End event"),
                 objectType = c("startEvent", "endEvent"))
flows <- tibble(id = c("flow1", "flow2"), 
               name = c("flow1", "flow2"),
               sourceRef = c("start", "task"), 
               targetRef = c("task", "end"),
               objectType = c("sequenceFlow", "sequenceFlow"))

# Create the BPMN model
model <- create_bpmn(nodes, flows, events)

# Render the BPMN diagram
render_bpmn(
  model,              # Use 'model' here
  viewer.suppress = FALSE, 
  width = NULL,       
  height = NULL,      
  elementId = NULL,   
  xml_version_number = "1.0",
  xml_encoding_declaration = "UTF-8" 
)


Can you check my edit of your title please: by "linear fashion" do you mean left-to -right?

Yeah, that is fine. The process should flow linearly from left to right and not diagonally downwards

@user20650, did you have a crack at it?

nope sorry @Irfan. I did have a quick look at the code in the bpmnR package and there was not an easy, relevant option to change the orientation that I could see. Perhaps something in create_xml2.R  ...??? or otherwise lower down in bpmn. You could contact the maintainer("bpmnR"): [1] "Gert Janssenswillen gert.janssenswillen@uhasselt.be"

As noted in the comments, there is no out-of-the-box way to achieve this, but can modify the model object using the xml2 package and some trial and error.
The example below uses the coordinates 0,0 as an anchor to make it a bit easier to determine where to plot each element. Note that the x and y offsets are based on the default sizes of each object:

36 x 36 for the start/end nodes
100 x 80 for the Task name object

If these differ for your model object, you can examine model$xml to find the width and height variables and adjust your offsets to suit.
library(dplyr)
library(bpmnR)
library(xml2)

# Create data for BPMN elements
nodes <- tibble(id = "task", name = "Task name",
                objectType = "task", gatewayDirection = NA)
events <- tibble(id = c("start", "end"), 
                 name = c("Start event", "End event"),
                 objectType = c("startEvent", "endEvent"))
flows <- tibble(id = c("flow1", "flow2"), 
                name = c("flow1", "flow2"),
                sourceRef = c("start", "task"), 
                targetRef = c("task", "end"),
                objectType = c("sequenceFlow", "sequenceFlow"))

# Create the BPMN model
model <- create_bpmn(nodes, flows, events)

# Convert model xml as an xml object
mod_xml <- read_xml(model$xml)

# Return name and id values for all mod_xml elements (your id values will differ)
nodes <- xml_find_all(mod_xml, "//*[@id and @name]")

nodes <- data.frame(
  id = sapply(nodes, function(x) xml_attr(x, "id")),
  name = sapply(nodes, function(x) xml_attr(x, "name"))
)

nodes
#                                        id        name
# 1 id_050c2a4c-6205-4f2b-a1e1-45ce40c2584c   Task name
# 2 id_d863e666-fd07-4778-bfef-e517d686234d Start event
# 3 id_1967ee21-3f1c-46db-b944-9a949a46b757   End event
# 4 id_af62389a-4f4b-4cbc-9e33-8b77f615a3cf       flow1
# 5 id_1eefc447-26a0-4543-a655-a93ca9eefcd2       flow2

# Path to Task name
t_xy <- paste0(
  ".//bpmndi:BPMNShape[@bpmnElement='", nodes[nodes$name == "Task name", "id"], "']"
  )

# Return Task name BPMNShape
shape_node <- xml_find_first(mod_xml, t_xy)

# Get Task name coordinates
bounds_node <- xml_find_first(shape_node, ".//dc:Bounds")

# Adjust coordinates
xml_set_attr(bounds_node, "x", "200")
xml_set_attr(bounds_node, "y", "0")

# Path to Start event
s_xy <- paste0(
  ".//bpmndi:BPMNShape[@bpmnElement='", nodes[nodes$name == "Start event", "id"], "']"
)

# Return BPMNShape
shape_node <- xml_find_first(mod_xml, s_xy)

# Get Start event coordinates
bounds_node <- xml_find_first(shape_node, ".//dc:Bounds")

# Adjust coordinates
xml_set_attr(bounds_node, "x", "0")
xml_set_attr(bounds_node, "y", "0")

# Path to End event
e_xy <- paste0(
  ".//bpmndi:BPMNShape[@bpmnElement='", nodes[nodes$name == "End event", "id"], "']"
)

# Return End event BPMNShape
shape_node <- xml_find_first(mod_xml, e_xy)

# Get plot coordinates
bounds_node <- xml_find_first(shape_node, ".//dc:Bounds")

# Adjust coordinates
xml_set_attr(bounds_node, "x", "464")
xml_set_attr(bounds_node, "y", "40")

# Path to flow1
f1_xy <- paste0(
  ".//bpmndi:BPMNEdge[@bpmnElement='", nodes[nodes$name == "flow1", "id"], "']"
)

# Return BPMNEdge
shape_node <- xml_find_first(mod_xml, f1_xy)

# Get plot coordinates
bounds_node <- xml_find_all(shape_node, ".//di:waypoint")

# Adjust coordinates
xml_set_attr(bounds_node[1], "x", "36")
xml_set_attr(bounds_node[1], "y", "18")
xml_set_attr(bounds_node[2:3], "x", "200")
xml_set_attr(bounds_node[2:3], "y", "40")

# Path to flo2
f2_xy <- paste0(
  ".//bpmndi:BPMNEdge[@bpmnElement='", nodes[nodes$name == "flow2", "id"], "']"
)

# Return BPMNEdge
shape_node <- xml_find_first(mod_xml, f2_xy)

# Get plot coordinates
bounds_node <- xml_find_all(shape_node, ".//di:waypoint")

# Adjust coordinates
xml_set_attr(bounds_node[1], "x", "300")
xml_set_attr(bounds_node[1], "y", "40")
xml_set_attr(bounds_node[2:3], "x", "464")
xml_set_attr(bounds_node[2:3], "y", "58")

# Update model xml
model$xml <- mod_xml

# Render updated model
render_bpmn(
  model, 
  viewer.suppress = FALSE, 
  width = NULL, 
  height = NULL, 
  elementId = NULL,
  xml_version_number = "1.0",
  xml_encoding_declaration = "UTF-8"
)


